# Empty emailAddress fields from comments and permissions API

Tags: google-drive-api

When I attempt to query comments or permissions for a google drive file, the response has no value for the "emailAddress" field. This happens regardless of whether I include the emailAddress attribute in the 'fields' param or not.

I see that on the API reference it says: "The email address of the user. This may not be present in certain contexts if the user has not made their email address visible to the requester." but I'm not sure what this means?

I am also the administrator for the domain I am building an app for, so if there's a setting I need to change, that is also possible.

Comment: That means the owner did not enable his personal emailAddress for public viewing which is outside of your control.

Comment: Let’s say I am the owner, since I administer the gsuite accounts. How can I enable this?